# How to link picture in HTML that is stored locally?

Tags: html

```
<img src="/assets/supermarket.jpg" width="500" height="250" alt="supermarket aisle">
```

I have the picture stored in a "assets" folder in the same main folder as the main.html file but I can't seem to make the picture show up.

Comment: try checking spelling (like if the image format is png and spelling mistakes)?

Comment: /assets/supremarket.jpg is relative path to the location of the html from where you are calling the image. You can try using absolute path from the route of the application via ~/pathtoassestsfolder/assets/supremarket.jpg

Comment: try `./assets/supermarket.jpg.`

Comment: What worked for me is ../assets/supermarket.jpg

Answer (score 0):

May be the initial slash. Try without it.

```
src="assets/supermarket.jpg"
```

Comment: Still isn't working I tried multiple ways to make it work.